# Button in bootstrap does not function

Tags: php, database, twitter-bootstrap

Submit button does not functioning when I click. All of the code seem to have no errors, but it just does not inserted to my database. I am currently using bootstrap. I don't know what is the error I am having.

index.html

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <div class="form-area">  
                <form role="form">
                    <br style="clear:both">
                <h3 style="margin-bottom: 25px; text-align: center;">Schedule Form</h3>
                <form name="form2" method="post" action="scheduleform.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tajuk" name="tajuk" placeholder="Tajuk" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="tarikh" name="tarikh" placeholder="Tarikh" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="mobile" name="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" type="textarea" id="maklumat" name="maklumat" placeholder="Maklumat" maxlength="140" rows="7"></textarea>
                    <span class="help-block"><p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">You have reached the limit</p></span>                    
                </div>

                    <button><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Form</button>
            </form></form>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
```

scheduleform.php

```
  <?php

$server = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$dbname = "kajangdb";

//Creating connection for mysqli

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);

//Checking connection

if($conn->connect_error){
 die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}



$tajuk = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tajuk']);
$tarikh = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tarikh']);
$mobile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['mobile']);
$maklumat = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['maklumat']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO schedule (tajuk, tarikh, mobile, maklumat) VALUES ('$tajuk', '$tarikh', '$mobile', '$maklumat')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

?>

Comment: why you have used form inside form?

Comment: @CyberAbhay I just noticed it, made changes already

Comment: Thanks, I did made adjustments on my code, but nothing seem to work.

Comment: Print all your $_POST variables and check all received then print your $sql query and check it in mysql will give you possible error

Comment: @CyberAbhay Ive made the change, it worked! Thanks a lot

Comment: @Iskanadar Glad to know it worked for you.have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Issues i found with your code.
1. You don't need to wrap form element with another form element
2.

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO schedule (tajuk, tarikh, mobile, maklumat) VALUES ('$tajuk', '$tarikh', '$mobile', '$maklumat')";
```

Here you added extra space after "schedule" and "VALUES" which may created problem. change your code as below.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO schedule(tajuk, tarikh, mobile, maklumat) VALUES('$tajuk', '$tarikh', '$mobile', '$maklumat')";
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Nested forms are definitely error-prone. Use more forms in a page, if
   you wish, but never nest them. Here you are using `form2` inside
   another one. Don't do that, delete the outer one.

2) Your submit button syntax is wrong. Use `input` OR `button`.

Instead of:

```
<button><input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Form</button>
```

use:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" />
```

or:

```
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Submit Form</button>
```

3) Provide validation on `$_POST` values. Like:

```
if (
        !isset($_POST['tajuk']) ||
        !isset($_POST['tarikh']) ||
        !isset($_POST['mobile']) ||
        !isset($_POST['maklumat'])
    ) {
    echo 'Error: not all values are valid. Please provide valid values.';
}

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);
//...
```

---

I recommend you to always prepare your sql statements for execution, in order to avoid the SQL injection risks. Use `prepare()` before querying. See: [mysqli::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Also use exception handling. See please [The mysqli_sql_exception class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-sql-exception.php)

### EDIT 1:

It is not allowed to use paragraphs (`<p>`) inside spans (`<span>`). Use other container types, like `<div>` instead of `<span>`. So, replace

```
<span class="help-block">
    <p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">
        You have reached the limit
    </p>
</span>
```

with

```
<div class="help-block">
    <p id="characterLeft" class="help-block ">
        You have reached the limit
    </p>
</div>
```